# NSSavePanel savePanel call going into infinite loop

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsopenpanel, nssavepanel

`NSSavePanel * savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];` call is going into infinite loop with below message:

> 2016-02-15 12:00:16.641 myApp[25026:693813] Localizable string
>   "TG_DEFAULT_6078" not found in strings table "Localizable" of bundle
>   CFBundle 0x103070db0
>   < /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FinderKit.framework> (framework,
>   loaded).

I am using xcode 7.0.1 and OS X 10.10.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable `Show non-localized strings` option in scheme.

[image]